# @Data from lombok in Android Studio doesn't work

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, lombok

I have proper [dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJx2X.png)

And lombok plugin was installed, so Android Studio know where generation was applied but i still got an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DeNP.png)

Please can anyone give me idea what is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**

from kotlin 1.7.20 with K2 compiler it is possible.

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew1720.html#support-for-kotlin-k2-compiler-plugins

**OLD:**

Ok, I guess my problem somewhat solved. My project have mixed Kotlin\Java code, I found this closed issue in project lombok: https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/1169

Corresponding to this lombok cant work in Kotlin\Java code normal way cause reasons... and there is two solutions:

1. Multi module project where all Java code with lobmok separated from Kotlin code and java module should using only java compiler.
2. Use special plugin from Kotlin which in part solving issue https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lombok.html

Another dum-dum solution: drop lombok annotation on java class and then using some instruments delombok it.This way no javac will be required.